# Writing Data from Excel to Word

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

- I want to use Excel to store "tag names" in column A and their associated "replacement text" in Column B.  When the code runs, it needs to collect each tag, one at a time (row by row), search an entire Word document for those words, and replace them with their corresponding replacements.
- I noticed the special tags in the headers and footers weren't being replaced.  I turned to this article (http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm) and found that working with a range of ranges (or cycling through all available Story Ranges in the document) I was able to do this.
- I improved my code, as recommended in the link above and it worked, so long as my code was embedded in my "Normal" Word file, thereby using my VBA code from Word to operate on another Word document.  However, the goal is to use VBA Excel to operate the replacements while reading an Excel file.
- When I moved the code to Excel, I'm getting hung up on an Automation error which reads,

> "Run-time error '-2147319779 (8002801d)': Automation error  Library not registered.".

- I've looked for answers from reviewing the Registry to using "Word.Application.12" in place of "Word.Application".

I have a Windows 7, 64-Bit machine, with Microsoft Office 2007.  I have the following libraries selected:

- Excel:

  - Visual Basic For Applications
  - Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library
  - OLE Automation
  - Microsoft Access 12.0 Object Library
  - Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library
  - Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library
  - Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
  - Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library
- Word:

  - Visual Basic For Applications
  - Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library
  - OLE Automation
  - Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library

I have no issues with operating inside of Excel with regard to VBA.  Normally, I will be passing a set of strings to this function, but for now, I have embedded the strings inside of the function, as if I am only planning on swapping one string (for any number of instances), with another predetermined string.

```
Function Story_Test()
Dim File As String
Dim Tag As String
Dim ReplacementString As String

Dim a As Integer

Dim WordObj As Object
Dim WordDoc As Object
Dim StoryRange As Word.Range
Dim Junk As Long

Dim BaseFile As String

'Normally, these lines would be strings which get passed in
File = "Z:\File.docx"
Tag = "{{Prepared_By}}"
ReplacementString = "Joe Somebody"

'Review currently open documents, and Set WordDoc to the correct one
'Don't worry, I already have error handling in place for the more complex code
Set WordObj = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
BaseFile = Basename(File)
For a = 1 To WordObj.Documents.Count
    If WordObj.Documents(a).Name = BaseFile Then
        Set WordDoc = WordObj.Documents(a)
        Exit For
    End If
Next a

'This is a fix provided to fix the skipped blank Header/Footer problem
Junk = WordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.StoryType


'Okay, this is the line where we can see the error.
'When this code is run from Excel VBA, problem.  From Word VBA, no problem.
'Anyone known why this is???
'***********************************************************************
For Each StoryRange In WordObj.Documents(a).StoryRanges
'***********************************************************************
    Do
        'All you need to know about the following function call is
        ' that I have a function that works to replace strings.
        'It works fine provided it has valid strings and a valid StoryRange.
        Call SearchAndReplaceInStory_ForVariants(StoryRange, Tag, _
          ReplacementString, PreAdditive, FinalAdditive)
        Set StoryRange = StoryRange.NextStoryRange
    Loop Until StoryRange Is Nothing
Next StoryRange

Set WordObj = Nothing
Set WordDoc = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: The problem could not be better explained. One suggestion is to check the references in the Word-VBA project and see which one(s) are missing in the Excel-VBA project

Comment: The only slight issue that would be relative to your solution would be that in VBA Excel I have Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library, and in VBA Word, I have Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library, as stated above.  But, this doesn't appear to be a fix.

Comment: Just to make sure, doo you mean that you tried changing the reference in Excel-VBA from Office14 to Office12?

Comment: In my Word VBA, I only have the "Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library" option.  In Excel VBA, I only have the "Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library" option.  Do you belive there might be a difference here??  Uhh...one that might relate to the Automation error??

Comment: The possibility exists, i would say. Because from the error message, it is clearly an automation problem. Somewhere one of these DLLs is trying to access another DLL that is not installed. for the least, I would suggest that you try your code on an installation that has exactly the same libraries installed.. somehow, office14 or office12 but not both

Comment: I will look into this when I have another machine available to me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each StoryRange In WordObj.Documents(a).StoryRanges
```

should probably be

```
For Each StoryRange In WordDoc.StoryRanges
```

since you just assigned that in the loop above.

Comment: yeah, and it seems that "a" may become out of bounds, isnt it? but I doubt that this fixes the problem in the case where the BaseFile is found

Comment: As for the "a" variable becoming out of bounds...the "a" will start at 1 and work toward the number of word documents.  However, if there aren't any, the more complex code allows for error handling which actually is caught in the couple lines above, using "GetObject(, "Word.Application")".  If the event that WordObj.Documents.Count = 0 (for some crazy reason), then the For loop will have ended before it began, thereby bypassing it from the start.  In that case, the "WordDoc" won't be initialized, but not to worry, more error handling.  Thank you!

Comment: Tim Williams...while I can see why you would have recommended that change, there appears to be no difference with regard to the error being provided.  If you were to write simple code used for the purpose of replacing a string within any location of a word document, all done from Excel VBA, how would you do it??  Perhaps I am not using the most effective manner??  Thank you in advance for your time!!!

Comment: @TheKirkwoods a will be out of bound if the BaseFile is not found in the WordObj.Documents collection. You need to remember that in this case, a will have the value *WordObj.Documents.Count + 1*. That is why I warned about a possible out-of-bound. But as I said, this should not occur if BaseFile is found.

Comment: Ahh...okay, yes.  That makes sense.  Perhaps I need to just move the lower code into the for loop for the condition that BaseFile is found.  Thank you!

Comment: @TheKirkwoods - you and A.S.H. are correct: my suggestion doesn't help - in the case where the document is located correctly in the loop, `a` will be the correct value, and if it's not located then neither `WordDoc` nor `WordObj.Documents(a)` will reference anything (but with slightly different error messages)

Answer (score 0):

For now, I will have to conclude, as I don't have the possibility of testing the contrary, that there is a difference between using Microsoft Office 12 Object Library in one VBA environment, and Microsoft Office 14 Object Library in another.  I don't have the means/authorizations to change either, so I must conclude, for now that is, that the difference between the two is the culprit.  So, if I was to go forward and expect different results, I would assume Microsoft Office 12 Object Library to be the correct library, where 14 has a few differences that I am not aware of.

Thank you to all who provided input.  If you have any other suggestions, we can discuss and forward.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is to update a bunch of links spread over body & Headers footers.
I didn't write this only from memory made a bunch of fixes, inclusions and tweaks.
It shows you how to cover all the different sections and can easily be modified to work within your parameters.
Please post your final code once done.

```
Public Sub UpdateAllFields()
Dim doc As Document
Dim wnd As Window
Dim lngMain As Long
Dim lngSplit As Long
Dim lngActPane As Long
Dim rngStory As Range
Dim TOC As TableOfContents
Dim TOA As TableOfAuthorities
Dim TOF As TableOfFigures
Dim shp As Shape
Dim sctn As Section
Dim Hdr As HeaderFooter
Dim Ftr As HeaderFooter

' Set Objects
Set doc = ActiveDocument
Set wnd = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow

' get Active Pane Number
lngActPane = wnd.ActivePane.Index

' Hold View Type of Main pane
lngMain = wnd.Panes(1).View.Type

' Hold SplitSpecial
lngSplit = wnd.View.SplitSpecial

' Get Rid of any split
wnd.View.SplitSpecial = wdPaneNone

' Set View to Normal
wnd.View.Type = wdNormalView

' Loop through each story in doc to update
For Each rngStory In doc.StoryRanges
    If rngStory.StoryType = wdCommentsStory Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
        ' Update fields
        rngStory.Fields.Update
        Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
    Else
        ' Update fields
        rngStory.Fields.Update
    End If
Next

'Loop through text boxes and update
For Each shp In doc.Shapes
    With shp.TextFrame
        If .HasText Then
            shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Fields.Update
        End If
    End With
Next

' Loop through TOC and update
For Each TOC In doc.TablesOfContents
    TOC.Update
Next

' Loop through TOA and update
For Each TOA In doc.TablesOfAuthorities
    TOA.Update
Next

' Loop through TOF and update
For Each TOF In doc.TablesOfFigures
    TOF.Update
Next

For Each sctn In doc.Sections
    For Each Hdr In sctn.Headers
        Hdr.Range.Fields.Update
        For Each shp In Hdr.Shapes
            With shp.TextFrame
                If .HasText Then
                    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Fields.Update
                End If
            End With
        Next shp
    Next Hdr
    For Each Ftr In sctn.Footers
        Ftr.Range.Fields.Update
        For Each shp In Ftr.Shapes
            With shp.TextFrame
                If .HasText Then
                    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Fields.Update
                End If
            End With
        Next shp
    Next Ftr
Next sctn

' Return Split to original state
wnd.View.SplitSpecial = lngSplit

' Return main pane to original state
wnd.Panes(1).View.Type = lngMain

' Active proper pane
wnd.Panes(lngActPane).Activate

' Close and release all pointers
Set wnd = Nothing
Set doc = Nothing
End Sub
```